# how to solve the variable coefficients second order ODE like this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a homework below.

Solve the equation:
$$
y''+\frac{5}{x}y'+2xy=0 \quad\quad (y=z/x^{2})
$$
I only can get
$$
y''=\frac{z''}{x^2}-4\frac{z'}{x^3}+6\frac{z}{x^4}
$$
$$
y'=\frac{z'}{x^2}-2\frac{z}{x^3}
$$
the equation still is a variable coefficients second order ODE.

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar (or expected to be familiar) with Bessel functions? If not, you may have an error in your problem statement.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with Bessel function. But I still don't know how to solve the equation other than series solution.

Comment: Ah, OK. The problem is trying to get you to massage the equation into the form of Bessel's equation by substituting a different function for $y$. The given substitution $y = z(x)/x^2$ gets you part of the way there, but you'll need a substitution for $x$ to finish it off.

Comment: Maybe the [Frobenius Method](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusMethod.html) would help you to find a solution.

Comment: how to substitution for x?@eyeballfrog

Comment: General solution is

$$y(\text{x})\mapsto\frac{c_2 J_{\frac{4}{3}}\left(\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2} x^{3/2}\right)}{x^2}-\frac{c_1 J_{-\frac{4}{3}}\left(\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{2} x^{3/2}\right)}{x^2}$$

with $J_{n}(z)$ the Bessel function of the first kind.

Answer (score 1):

After substituting $z,z'.z''$ OP found, in the given ODE, we get
$$x^2z''+xz'+(2x^3-4)z=0.\tag 1$$
This is not a [Bessel's ODE](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html). Considering eyeballfrog's hint in the comments (unfortunately he didn't write it), we try a substitution $x=At^{2/3}$ to convert this equation into Bessel's ODE. Then
$$z'=\frac{\dot z}{\dot x}=\frac{3}{2A}t^{1/3}\dot z$$
and
$$z''=\frac{3}{2A}\frac13t^{-2/3}\frac{3}{2A}t^{1/3}\dot z+(\frac{3}{2A}t^{1/3})^2\ddot z=\frac{9}{4A^2}t^{2/3}\ddot z+\frac{3}{4A^2}t^{-1/3}\dot z.$$
If we substitute $x, z'$ and $z''$ in $(1)$, we have
$$\frac94 t^2\ddot z+\frac94 t\dot z+2A^3(t^2-\frac{2}{A^3})z=0.$$
To obtain a Bessel ODE, we set $2A^3=\frac94$ and hence $A=\frac{3^{2/3}}{2}$ and $x=\frac{3^{2/3}}{2}t^{2/3}$. Now, $z$ satisfies the Bessel's ODE
$$t^2\ddot z+t\dot z+(t^2-\frac{16}{9})z=0\tag2$$
and has the solution $z=c_1J_{4/3}(t)+c_2J_{-4/3}(t).$ We substitute $t=\frac{(2x)^{3/2}}{3}$ in $y=z/x^2$ to find the solution gpmath gave in the comments.

Note: Wolfram Alpha called this equation [Emden-Fowler equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27%2B%285%2Fx%29y%27%2B2xy%3D0) but its solution is Bessel. Applied mathematics is messy.